# Get ListBlobs() sorted by LastModifiedDate?

Tags: azure, blob, c#-3.0, azure-storage

I have 30000 images in blob storage and I want to fetch the images in descending order of modified date. Is there any way to fetch it in chunks of 1000 images per call?

Here is my code but this take too much time. Basically can i sort `ListBlobs()` by LastUpdated date?

```
CloudBlobContainer rootContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("installations");
CloudBlobDirectory dir1;
var items = rootContainer.ListBlobs(id + "/Cameras/" + camId.ToString() + "/", false);

foreach (var blob in items.OfType<CloudBlob>()
    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Properties.LastModified).Skip(1000).Take(500))
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Basically can i sort ListBlobs() by LastUpdated date?

No, you can't do server-side sorting on `LastUpdated`. Blob Storage service returns the data sorted by blob's name. You would need to fetch the complete data on the client and sort it there.

Other alternative would be to store the blob's information (like blob's URL, last modified date etc.) in a SQL Database and fetch the list from there. There you will have the ability to sort the data any way you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted the blobs in last modified order as in the below example and it is the only solution I could think of :)

```
    /**
 * list the blob items in the blob container, ordered by the last modified date
 * @return
 */
public List<FileProperties> listFiles() {
    
    Iterable<ListBlobItem> listBlobItems = rootContainer.listBlobs();
    List<FileProperties> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ListBlobItem listBlobItem : listBlobItems) {
        if (listBlobItem instanceof CloudBlob) {
            String substring = ((CloudBlob) listBlobItem).getName();
            FileProperties info = new FileProperties(substring, ((CloudBlob) listBlobItem).getProperties().getLastModified());

            list.add(info);
        }

    }

    // to sort the listed blob items in last modified order
    list.sort(new Comparator<FileProperties>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(FileProperties o1, FileProperties o2) {
            return new Long(o2.getLastModifiedDate().getTime()).compareTo(o1.getLastModifiedDate().getTime());
        }
    });

    return  list;
}
```